Looking for a way to get the details from revision graph via api in Perforce
I work on a MonoRepo in perforce so we have multiple branch.
I am trying to create an api which will fetch  all the branch name where a file has changes .
basically what revision Graph shows and I am only trying to fetch the branch names which can be seen under Revision_graph-> Details -> Revision
Is there any API which can help me scrap that data from Revision graph.
any doc or any code snap will help.
Thanks

Revision Graph is driven primarily by the p4 filelog command, which includes detailed data about all of the revisions of a given file, including (but not limited to) where it has been integrated.
Since this is a P4D server command it's available through all P4 client APIs, but it is not available via the Swarm web API.  For an example of building something Revision-Graph-like in a web interface, check out the revision graph feature in the old Mediawiki plugin, or the "variants" feature that was specifically for discovering all of the branches of a given project (which sounds like what you're trying to build).
